# I'm upgrade windows 8 to windows 8.1, if i refresh / remove?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1

Guys I'm upgraded Windows 8 Single Language to Windows 8.1 Single Language,

i wanna ask if i "refresh the pc" or "remove everything and reinstall windows", is the result will bring me back to `Windows 8.0 Single Language` or will it be `Windows 8.1 Single Language`?

My original OS is `Windows 8 Single Language`.

[image]]

Comment: Unless you spent the time to upgrade those images they are unlikely to even work.  If they do work they will reset your system back the original release of `Windows 8.0`.

Comment: @Ramhound so how I keep my upgrade sir?

Comment: You don't.  If you want to `Refresh` or `Reset` your system you will have to install Windows 8.1 again after those operations are completed.

Comment: If you're current Windows 8.1 is fine, you can use recimg.exe (recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage) to create your own 8.1 recovery image : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/04/refresh-and-reset-your-pc.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 my currennt windows is windows 8. If i create recovery image like u said, can i refresh using my 8.1 recovery image?

Comment: I thought you already upgraded to 8.1?

Comment: @magicandre1981 yes, i did. I'm already upgraded to 8.1. Now i'm using win 8.1. If i create recovery image using recimg.exe (recimg -CreateImage C:\RefreshImage) on my upgraded 8.1, will refresh directed to my 8.1 recovery image?

Comment: if you run recimg under windows 8.1, you have the 8.1 refresh image and windows will use this 8.1 image. Run sfc and DISM before making the image, to make sure everything is fine so far.

Answer (score 0):

The default refresh image is Windows 8 in your case. But you can update that to a custom 8.1 yourself. For details **[see here](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/3610-refresh-windows-8-create-use-custom-recovery-image.html)**. Then you have to set that as active - [see here.](http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/9310-refresh-windows-8-set-custom-recovery-image-active.html)

However, you are probably better off making your own images because refreshing with the refresh image does not bring everything back. For that I recommend **[free Macrium.](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/73828-imaging-free-macrium.html?ltr=I)**